# Redmine duplicate URL access / & /redmine

Tags: apache, url, redmine

I managed to get my Redmine reachable at a example.org/redmine URL.
But actually, it's still reachable at example.org/

I can't manage to make it work only on the /redmine alias.
Here is my configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/share/gems/gems/passenger-5.0.11/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /usr/local/share/gems/gems/passenger-5.0.11
     PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby
     PassengerUser apache
   </IfModule>


  DocumentRoot /var/www
  PassengerAppRoot /var/www/redmine

  RailsBaseURI /redmine
  Alias /redmine /var/www/redmine/public
  TransferLog "logs/redmine_acess_log"
  ErrorLog "logs/redmine_error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

When I enter example.org/zriogjqoerqgj I'd like to have the default ErrorDocument, not something hooked up by Redmine.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Directory directive, for example:

```
<Directory /var/www/redmine>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And another one

```
<Directory /var/www>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Virtual Host shoud looks like this:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80> 
        ServerName example.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        ErrorLog logs/redmine_error_log
        <Directory "/var/www/">
                Allow from all
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>

        Alias /redmine /var/www/redmine/public/
        <Location /redmine>
                PassengerBaseURI /redmine
                PassengerAppRoot /var/www/redmine
        </Location>
        <Directory /var/www/redmine/public/ >
                Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I did this solution following the [Passenger documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/#deploying-an-app-to-a-sub-uri-or-subdirectory)